# Sails.js - Creating a view to edit a model

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have a simple model as follows:

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {

        firstName: 'STRING',
        lastName: 'STRING',
        contact: 'STRING',
        email: 'STRING'

    }

};
```

I already have an index action that displays all the humans. This is the corresponding view:

```
<h1>List of all humans</h1>

<ul>
<% _.each(humans, function(model) { %>
<li><%= model.firstName %> /// <%= model.lastName %> /// <%= model.contact %> ///     <%= model.email %> <a href="/human/edit"><button id="<%=model.firstName %>"type="button">Edit</button> </a></li> 
<% }) %>
</ul>
```

What I want to accomplish is that every time someone clicks on the EDIT button, to display a view containing all the information of that specific model (localhost:1337/human/edit/:id). How can I write my controller? How can I tell my controller that I want THAT specific model to be displayed and route it properly?

Thank you!

Comment: No, I am not a robot. It is just that when you provided the answer, it quickly solved my issue. Moreover, since this is quite an old issue for me, I have not checked it lately :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should point browser to `localhost:1337/human/edit/:id` url, where :id is your particular model's `id`. For example

```
<ul>
<% _.each(humans, function(model) { %>
  <li><%= model.firstName %> <a href="/human/edit/<%= model.id %>"><button id="<%=model.firstName %>" type="button">Edit</button> </a>
  </li> 
<% }) %>
</ul>
```

This will automatically execute `Human.edit` controller with `id` param set to particular model's id. You don't have to write any custom routes, this is default behaviour.

Example of Human/edit controller action:

```
edit: function(req, res) {
  Human.findById( req.param('id') )
    .done(function(err, human) {
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err, 500);
      } else {
        if (human.length) {
          res.json(human[0]);
        } else {
          res.send('Human not found', 500);
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Here I return model encoded as json in response, for simplicity, but you can use your view.

In addition, `firstName` property is not the best value to use as buttons `id` attribute, because it should be unique.